# Android Filter Intent Chooser

Tags: android, file, android-intent, filter, explorer

I would like to filter the list you see below. Only file-explorer should be choosable.

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/" + getContext().getPackageName() + "/Files");
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.openFolder)));
```

[image: Example]

**EDIT:**

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. There is no magic `Intent` that always only opens some magic app category.

First, anyone can write any app to respond to any desired implicit `Intent`.

Second, there is no universal definition of "file explorer". What *you* think a "file explorer" is may differ from what other developers think a "file explorer" is, which in turn may differ from what *users* think a "file explorer" is. A user's device may not even *have* a "file explorer", from anyone's definition.

Comment: I created something similar that only shows email-provider that works well!

Comment: @CommonsWare so is there any guidelines to consider in case we're going to develop content managers ?

Comment: @XxGoliathusxX: Feel free to explain how you paid for testing thousands of Android devices and millions of Android apps (growing daily), to confirm that your code "only shows email-provider". I have no doubt that for the few devices you tested and the few apps on those devices, that your code might "only shows email-provider".

Comment: @CommonsWare How can I send you a screenshot?

Comment: @XxGoliathusxX: You can edit your question and add a screenshot.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok I did. It shows explorer and email provider

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `Intent`, it would open a ES File Explorer

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)));
intent.setPackage("com.estrongs.android.pop");
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Comment: I believe he's asking for options to open desired directory in a content manager app, not sending a file, right?

Comment: It should not open ES explicitly but a list of file-explorer!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the directory exists then try this :

```
Intent fileManagers = new Intent();
fileManagers.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                .getAbsolutePath());
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(dir);
fileManagers.setDataAndType(uri, "file/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(fileManagers, null));
```

Comment: This opens Google Drive on my device

Comment: Updated answer, try this one

Answer (score 0):

You can call the below function 
**type** is the package name of file-explorer
like if you want to share data to Twitter call it like  **initShareIntent("com.twitter.android");**

```
  private void initShareIntent(String type) {
        boolean found = false;
        Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/jpeg");

        // gets the list of intents that can be loaded.
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
        if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
            for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
                if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(type) ||
                        info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(type)) {


                 //Share Data here

                    share.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), share_type + " not found in Device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select"));
        }
    }
```

It will only open the particular app to share data. Try this and let me know if it helped you

Comment: what is type and share_type?

Comment: I dont want to share data. I want to open it

Comment: share_type is a string in my application is the sharing application name, yes it will open the application which you have choose, call it like initShareIntent("package name");